# Adding array of JRadioButtons with variable length to a JWindow

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jradiobutton, jwindow

Hello everyone I was trying to add an array of variable length to a JWindow but I am getting a run time error. Want help from here ..

Here is my code :

```
    package components;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class FullDay extends javax.swing.JWindow {

    public FullDay() {
        initComponents();
    }                         
    private void initComponents() {

        int i;
//to get the no of days of the current month.

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int maxdays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

//Creating an array of radiobuttons having size equal to the no of days of the current //month

        for(i=0; i<maxdays; i++) {
            jRadioButton[maxdays] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
            getContentPane().add(jRadioButton[i]);
        }        

        pack();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FullDay().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton[];
}
```

But the error I am getting is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at components.FullDay.initComponents(FullDay.java:18)
at components.FullDay.<init>(FullDay.java:8)
at components.FullDay$1.run(FullDay.java:30)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to initialize the i-th field of the array, instead of always initializing the last one:

```
 jRadioButton[i] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
```

instead of:

```
 jRadioButton[maxdays] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
```

Also, as the previous answers stated, create the array itself outside of the loop.

Comment: Hay Steltem  please make this programme to work. I tried everything dude. nt working even after your suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the `jRadioButton` array is created before assigning.

Comment: Hay StanislavL please make this programme to work. I tried everything dude .

Comment: Hay Mavrick please pay me for making this programme to work or try more than everything dude.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialise your array of JRadioButton

```
JRadioButton jRadioButton[] = new JRadioButton[someValue];
```

Comment: Try the following                                           JRadioButton jRadioButton[] = new JRadioButton[maxdays];                   for(i=0; i<maxdays; i++) {
            jRadioButton[i] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
            getContentPane().add(jRadioButton[i]);
}

Comment: @user2194480 if you can't use this (or any of the others) answer to fix your code yourself, you have to take a step back and fresh up/ learn some basics of java ;-)